# How do I tell what Java app a process is?

Tags: java, ps

I run Eclipse in my Ubuntu 17.04. `ps -A |grep java` shows several processes. How can I tell which one is Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
jps -l
```

It will list the instrumented Java Virtual Machines (JVMs) on the target system.
This is more verbose than PS, maibe it can help you